# WordPress посадка

Tags: wordpress

Не могу до конца понять принцип посадки на WP.

К примеру, у меня есть тестовый сайт из главной и четырёх внутренних страниц. На каждой страничке есть хедер, контент, и футер, сайдбара нету. Футер и хедер в отдельные файлы, для главной home.php, для остальных страниц также отдельные page страницы.

Как правильнее или лучше делать посадку контента ? У меня в голове это так, для каждой страницы я делаю свою главную рубрику, которая в свою очередь будет иметь под-рубрики. Каждая подрубрика отвечает за секции страницы. И уже внутри подрубрик я создаю записи которые будут являться контентом секций. Правильный ли это подход ?

Comment: Блин "посадка", Структура данных Рубрики никакого отношения к страницам не имеют.   См https://ru.wordpress.org/support/topic/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE/#post-155549

Comment: спасибо большое, я уже читал кодекс, но единой структуры в голове так и не сложилось до сих пор. Все примеры в ютубе связаны с посадкой блога, хотелось бы понять как делать посадку многостраничного сайта, или хотя бы лендинга.